# Magento Shipping APi's

Tags: shipping, api, shipment, usps

How to get ordered items associated with tracking numbers?Magento by default does not save mapping between order items and their tracking number. In case there are multiple packages, single shipment and multiple tracking numbers then how can we identify which tracking number belong to which package??

Comment: What about `sales_flat_shipment_item`? There are items associated with each shipment, and each shipment may have its own tracking number.

Comment: Each shipment can have multiple tracking number. i want to retrieve the tracking number associated with the items..